# Flash Message on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

this is my controller method

```
def purchase

    if @item_point > current_user.points
        flash.keep[:notice] = "You dont have enough points to buy this item"
    else
        flash.keep[:notice] = "You have successfully redeemed this items, Thanks for the purchase."
    end
    render :json => flash
    p flash[:notice]
  end
```

and in my javascript ajax function's success i have written

```
$(".purchaseBtm button").click(function() {
    var button_id = this.id.split("-")[1];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/hhr/purchase',
            data : {
                button_id : button_id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('message: <%= flash[:notice]%>');
                    $('.flash-msg').html('');
                    $('.flash-'+button_id).text('<%= flash[:notice]%>')
            }
        }); 
    });
```

This ajax call goes on a button click which passes some values, with which @item_point is calculated.
Problem is in my terminal i'm getting the correct Flash message every time.
but in my Browser console sometimes i get the first flash message as correct and then the same flash message persists. I wont get the second flash message. But the terminal shows corectly(the p message.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this action is to only to render feedback message from server, then I would just render the hash containing the message, as there is no point to store it in special flash container.

```
if @item_point > current_user.points
  message = "You dont have enough points to buy this item"
else
  message = "You have successfully redeemed this items, Thanks for the purchase." }
end

render json: { notice: message }
```

Edit:

Then in your json use

```
success: function(response) {
            console.log('message: ' + response.notice);
                $('.flash-msg').html('');
                $('.flash-'+button_id).text(response.notice)
        }
```

Also remember to set type of ajax request to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: no i want to mode function inside that for and else loop..after i make this correct and your solution is not working..same as before